# Question - Recursive Function To Return Text File Permutations

Tags: c++

Basically, we have a homework assignment, to create a program in c++ that opens a text file ("**input.txt**"), and outputs to another file ("**output.txt**") the permutations of the text lines of the input file using a recursive algorithm.

I have tried implementing the recursive function but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I guess the Input and output files are good though (i think).

Any advice will be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string data; 
string file_contents; 

string permute()
{
string result;

ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("input.txt");   
int a = 0;
while (getline(inFile, file_contents))
{
    a++;
}
if (a == 1)
{
    ofstream OutFile;
}
else
{   
    ofstream OutFile;
}
return result;
}//perm

void accessFile()
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("input.txt");   
if (!inFile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error openning input file" << endl;
}
else 
{   
    while (getline(inFile, data))                                       
    {
        file_contents += data;
        file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }
    inFile.close();
}
ofstream OutFile;
OutFile.open("output.txt");
if(OutFile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error openning output file." << endl;
}
else
{
    OutFile << file_contents;
    permute();
    OutFile.close();
}
}//File

int main()
{
cout << "do you want to run the program?" << endl;
string input;
cin >> input;
if (input == "yes")
{
    accessFile();
}
else
{
exit;
}

return 0;
}//main
```

Let's say the input is:

```
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
```

The expected output is:

```
Line One
Line Two
Line Three

Line One
Line Three
Line Two

Line Two
Line One
Line Three

Line Two
Line Three
Line One

Line Three
Line One
Line Two

Line Three
Line Two
Line One
```

Comment: You are using C++, so you should do this with the algorithm `std::next_permutation`. Make a vector of strings for each line, which you permutate over.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of creating objects with meaningful values rather than create them with default values and immediately overwrite those values with meaningful ones. That is, in this code, change `ifstream inFile; inFile.open("input.txt");` to `ifstream inFile("input.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `OutFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: And while I'm at it, think about consistency. The code checks the input file with `if(!inFile.is_open())`, but it checks the output file with `if(OutFile.fail())`. Those two tests are slightly different, and a reader of the code will puzzle over why they are written differently. And, in general, to check the state of a stream, just use its implicit conversion to `bool`: `if(!inFile)` and `if(!OutFile)`.

Comment: Are you stuck on the algorithm or the implementation? Have you tried Googling "algorithm to generate all permutations"? You don't seem to have implemented any algorithm to generate the permutations. Also, don't guess that your I/O functions are good. *Know* they're good by testing them separately.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was managed to do by the advises you gave me! :)
Your help is greatly appreciated! hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested the problem can be solved by using  'std::next_permutation'.
However I think what @Mustafa Kalzi had in mind was more of a better understanding as to how to create such an algorithm.
I know it is an overdo but I found this problem interesting to solve and food for thought as a mathematical problem.
And regarding to some disadvantages of 'std::next_permutation' I created an alternative general algorithm for permutation problems.

Extra efforts has been made to have permutations as an **object** which only depends on the number of possible configurations and can be passed, 
 compared and ultimately used by several different objects, there for providing an almost complete control for the users!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/* Copyright (C) 2019 AKL.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/*just a simple rotator for an array of size(size_) elements.
 std::rotate is to cumbersome and needs sorting*/
template<typename value_t__, typename size_t__>
void rotation(value_t__* , size_t__ size_, decltype(size_) = 1);
/*an all encompassing function template for finding permutations of an array elements
 based on the inputed configuration value.
 since the it is ignorant to the contents of the array, it can be used with number of
 pointers but not for the iterators.
 in the case of iterators it is best to first fill a normal array with consecutive numbers
 then use the content as an index for operator[] of any container!
 please note that the main overhead is to create and fill the input array for each permutation
 but as it was stated contents remain untouched in contrast to std::next_permutation*/
template<typename value_t__, typename size_t__>
void permutation(value_t__* , size_t__ size_,
        decltype(size_));
/*Optionally an all-in-one class template to have incremental/decremental fully functional counter-like object
 which also includes the index array.
 in contrast to std::next_permutation, main advantages are  to have a method to know how many permutations
 have been passed by comparing it to other objects/values like a value and going forward and backward
 through permutations and not having to sort any thing before hand as it not sensitive to contents*/
template<typename size_t__ = std::size_t>
class permutations {
public:
    /*most useful and many of the required member functions for such classes
     ***please note that extra safety mechanisms like range check and safety against 0 size are not included***
     but these are easy to overcome by the user, so one can choose to optimize the usage for speed or safety!*/
    permutations(size_t__);
    permutations(const permutations&);
    void set_configuration(size_t__);
    size_t__& operator[](size_t__);
    size_t__ operator[](size_t__) const;
    size_t__ get_possibilities() const;
    permutations& operator++();
    permutations& operator--();
    permutations operator++(int);
    permutations operator--(int);
    operator size_t__() const;
    ~permutations();
private:
    size_t__ size_v;
    size_t__ possibilities;
    size_t__ configuration;
    size_t__* index;
};


/*assuming that the first argument to the program is the name of
 input file and the second argument would be the name of output file
 in posix it can be executed like:
./program_name input_file_name.txt output_file_name.txt 
*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //checking if the right arguments have been entered
    if ((not argc) or (argc > 3)) {
        std::cout << "wrong number of arguments " << argc - 1 << "should be 2"
                << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //opening the input file;
    std::ifstream in_file(argv[1]);
    //checking if the file is opened correctly
    if (not in_file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "can't open input file" << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //creating a vector for  lines
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    //filling the string vector by the reading from the input file lines
    for (std::string one_line; std::getline(in_file, one_line);
            lines.push_back(one_line))
        ;
    //creating an integer and filling it with the number of lines
    const std::size_t lines_count(lines.size());
    //permutations class templates are not able to handle 0 input so lets produce an error if that is the case
    if (not lines_count) {
        std::cout << argv[1] << " has zero lines!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << argv[1] << " has " << lines_count << " lines" << std::endl;
    //creating a permutations object to find right vector index for permutations
    permutations<> permutation_counter(lines_count);
    //getting the number of total possible permutations. optional!
    const std::size_t possible_permutations(
            permutation_counter.get_possibilities());
    std::cout << "number of possible permutations is " << possible_permutations
            << std::endl;
    /*alternatively this also can be done  with permutation function
     one only needs to first create an array for the indexes but
     filling the index array might be tedious*/
    //creating and opening the output file
    std::ofstream out_file(argv[2]);
    //checking if the file is opened correctly
    if (not out_file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "can't open output file" << argv[2] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //it is good to know how much of work is done for large files later!
    std::size_t done_percentage(0);
    //everything is set. now lets start going forward trough the permutations and writing to the output file!
    do {
        out_file << "********** permutation " << permutation_counter
                << " **********" << std::endl;
        for (std::size_t lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;
                out_file << lines[permutation_counter[lines_counter++]]
                        << std::endl)
            ;
        out_file << std::endl;
        //it is good to know how much of work is done for large files now!
        std::size_t done_percentage_now(
                (permutation_counter * 100) / possible_permutations);
        if (done_percentage_now != done_percentage) {
            done_percentage = done_percentage_now;
            std::cout << done_percentage << " % is done " << std::endl;
        }
    } while (++permutation_counter);
    /*alternatively --permutation_counter would also work to go backward trough the permutations!
     permutation_counter++/permutation_counter-- also work like post increment/decrement operators!
     by choosing any number from 0 to possible_permutations it is possible to go half or to a
     certain point  trough permutations!
     in addition by changing index array by using operator[] it would be possible to change any
     index there for the respective line or choose to only do the permutation for certain lines
     and/or even keep the rest unchanged!*/
    std::cout << "!!!finished!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

//definition for all functions.

template<typename value_t__, typename size_t__>
void rotation(value_t__* p_, size_t__ size_, decltype(size_) amount_) {
    for (size_t__ begin(0); begin < amount_; ++begin) {
        size_t__ index(begin);
        value_t__ backup(p_[index]);
        for (; (index += amount_) < size_; p_[index - amount_] = p_[index])
            ;
        p_[index - amount_] = backup;
    }
}

template<typename value_t__, typename size_t__>
void permutation(value_t__* p_, size_t__ size_,
        decltype(size_) configuration_) {
    /*above the size of 3 there is a simple regular formula,
     which is a combination of rotation of all elements in the current level then
     repeating a similar procedure for lower levels by recursive calls*/
    if (size_ > 3) {
        size_t__ factorial(--size_);
        for (size_t__ counter(size_); --counter; factorial *= counter)
            ;
        rotation(p_, size_ + 1, configuration_ / factorial);
        permutation(p_ + 1, size_, configuration_ % factorial);
        return;
    }
    /*case of size 3 is not regular but luckily very small so lets cover it as a switch-case statements.
     can easily be understood if one writes all the possibilities on a piece of paper (3 cm x 4 cm)*/
    if (size_ == 3) {
        switch (configuration_) {
        case 1:
            rotation(p_ + 1, 2);
            return;
        case 2:
            rotation(p_, 3);
            return;
        case 3:
            rotation(p_, 3);
            rotation(p_ + 1, 2);
            return;
        case 4:
            rotation(p_, 3, 2);
            return;
        case 5:
            rotation(p_, 3, 2);
            rotation(p_ + 1, 2);
            return;
        default:
            if (configuration_ > 5)
                permutation(p_, size_, configuration_ % 6);
            return;
        }
    }
    //case of size 2 is regular but it is after case of size 3. interestingly it is as tiny as one if statement!
    if (size_ == 2 and configuration_ % 2)
        rotation(p_, 2);
    //there is no permutation for case of size 1 and there is not even a case for lower sizes!
}


template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>::permutations(size_t__ size_v_) :
        size_v(size_v_), possibilities(size_v_), configuration(0), index(
                new size_t__[size_v_]) {
    for (; --size_v_; possibilities *= index[size_v_] = size_v_)
        ;
    index[0] = 0;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>::permutations(const permutations& another_) :
        size_v(another_.size_v), possibilities(another_.possibilities), configuration(
                another_.configuration), index(new size_t__[size_v]) {
    size_t__* another__index(another_.index);
    for (size_t__ counter(size_v); counter--; index[counter] =
            another__index[counter])
        ;
}
template<typename size_t__>
void permutations<size_t__>::set_configuration(size_t__ v_) {
    configuration = v_;
}
template<typename size_t__>
size_t__&
permutations<size_t__>::operator[](size_t__ index_) {
    return index[index_];
}
template<typename size_t__>
size_t__ permutations<size_t__>::operator[](size_t__ index_) const {
    return index[index_];
}
template<typename size_t__>
size_t__ permutations<size_t__>::get_possibilities() const {
    return possibilities;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>&
permutations<size_t__>::operator++() {
    if (not (++configuration < possibilities))
        configuration = 0;
    for (size_t__ counter(size_v); counter--; index[counter] = counter)
        ;
    permutation(index, size_v, configuration);
    return *this;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>&
permutations<size_t__>::operator--() {
    if (not configuration--)
        configuration = possibilities - 1;
    for (size_t__ counter(size_v); counter--; index[counter] = counter)
        ;
    permutation(index, size_v, configuration);
    return *this;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__> permutations<size_t__>::operator++(int) {
    permutations back(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return back;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__> permutations<size_t__>::operator--(int) {
    permutations back(*this);
    --(*this);
    return back;
}
template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>::operator size_t__() const {
    return configuration;
}

template<typename size_t__>
permutations<size_t__>::~permutations() {
    delete[] index;
}
```

Given input file:

```
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Result output file:

```
********** permutation 0 **********
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 1 **********
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 2 **********
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 3 **********
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 4 **********
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 5 **********
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3

********** permutation 6 **********
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 7 **********
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 8 **********
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 9 **********
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 10 **********
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 11 **********
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 12 **********
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 13 **********
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 14 **********
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 15 **********
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 16 **********
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 17 **********
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 18 **********
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 19 **********
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 20 **********
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 21 **********
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 22 **********
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 23 **********
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 3

********** permutation 24 **********
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 25 **********
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 26 **********
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 27 **********
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 28 **********
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 29 **********
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 30 **********
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 31 **********
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 32 **********
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 33 **********
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 34 **********
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 35 **********
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 36 **********
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 3

********** permutation 37 **********
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 38 **********
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 39 **********
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 40 **********
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 41 **********
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 42 **********
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 43 **********
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 44 **********
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 3

********** permutation 45 **********
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 46 **********
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 47 **********
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 48 **********
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 49 **********
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 50 **********
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 51 **********
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 52 **********
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 53 **********
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 54 **********
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 55 **********
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 56 **********
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 57 **********
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 58 **********
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 59 **********
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 60 **********
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 61 **********
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 62 **********
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 63 **********
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 64 **********
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 65 **********
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 66 **********
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 67 **********
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 68 **********
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 4

********** permutation 69 **********
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 3

********** permutation 70 **********
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 71 **********
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 72 **********
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 73 **********
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 74 **********
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 75 **********
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 76 **********
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 77 **********
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 78 **********
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 79 **********
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 80 **********
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 81 **********
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 82 **********
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 83 **********
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 84 **********
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 85 **********
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 86 **********
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 87 **********
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 88 **********
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 1

********** permutation 89 **********
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 4

********** permutation 90 **********
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 4

********** permutation 91 **********
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 0

********** permutation 92 **********
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 2

********** permutation 93 **********
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 4

********** permutation 94 **********
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 95 **********
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 96 **********
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 97 **********
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 98 **********
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 99 **********
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 100 **********
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 101 **********
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 3

********** permutation 102 **********
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 103 **********
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 104 **********
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 105 **********
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 106 **********
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 3

********** permutation 107 **********
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 0

********** permutation 108 **********
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 109 **********
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 110 **********
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 0

********** permutation 111 **********
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 2

********** permutation 112 **********
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 0

********** permutation 113 **********
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 1

********** permutation 114 **********
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 1

********** permutation 115 **********
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 3

********** permutation 116 **********
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 2

********** permutation 117 **********
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 1

********** permutation 118 **********
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 2

********** permutation 119 **********
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Console conversations and messages:

```
./program input.txt output.txt
input.txt has 5 lines
number of possible permutations is 120
1 % is done 
2 % is done 
3 % is done 
4 % is done 
5 % is done 
6 % is done 
7 % is done 
8 % is done 
9 % is done 
10 % is done 
11 % is done 
12 % is done 
13 % is done 
14 % is done 
15 % is done 
16 % is done 
17 % is done 
18 % is done 
19 % is done 
20 % is done 
21 % is done 
22 % is done 
23 % is done 
24 % is done 
25 % is done 
26 % is done 
27 % is done 
28 % is done 
29 % is done 
30 % is done 
31 % is done 
32 % is done 
33 % is done 
34 % is done 
35 % is done 
36 % is done 
37 % is done 
38 % is done 
39 % is done 
40 % is done 
41 % is done 
42 % is done 
43 % is done 
44 % is done 
45 % is done 
46 % is done 
47 % is done 
48 % is done 
49 % is done 
50 % is done 
51 % is done 
52 % is done 
53 % is done 
54 % is done 
55 % is done 
56 % is done 
57 % is done 
58 % is done 
59 % is done 
60 % is done 
61 % is done 
62 % is done 
63 % is done 
64 % is done 
65 % is done 
66 % is done 
67 % is done 
68 % is done 
69 % is done 
70 % is done 
71 % is done 
72 % is done 
73 % is done 
74 % is done 
75 % is done 
76 % is done 
77 % is done 
78 % is done 
79 % is done 
80 % is done 
81 % is done 
82 % is done 
83 % is done 
84 % is done 
85 % is done 
86 % is done 
87 % is done 
88 % is done 
89 % is done 
90 % is done 
91 % is done 
92 % is done 
93 % is done 
94 % is done 
95 % is done 
96 % is done 
97 % is done 
98 % is done 
99 % is done 
!!!finished!!!
```

The code is well commented and self explanatory. The declaration of the function and class templates at the beginning before the main function are alternate general way for solving such problems. And the the rest of the code in the main functions are used to showcase how to use these templates and is structured more or less like what others have done. Finally full definitions for the functions has be given in the end after the main function.

The key to understanding the problem is how to do it for under 4 variables which is not regular as 3!(3 x 2 x 6) is greater than number of variables (3) but 2!(2 x 1) is not greater than number of variables (2) so it is hard to determine how to  find rotations and permutations for cases under 4 variables. But interestingly above that threshold it becomes very regular and easy!

Based on a number which is a representation of a possible permutation, one only has to find a value for rotating and a value for permutation of the previous levels. For example consider the case of 4 variable which I designate as level 4 of the problem and the first call to the recursive function by User. There is 4!(4 x 3 x 2 x 1) = 24 total possibilities. Given number 20  as  a representation of a certain permutation, it is enough to divide 20 by 3!(6)  to find the representation of the rotation and getting the remainder of 20 by 3!(6) as the representation of  permutation of level 3, a second call and first recursive call to the function by itself.

As for 'std::next_permutation' one must not forget that the container must first be sorted otherwise it would not produce all the permutations. which also means the arrangement of the permutations is out the user control,  specially if it is desired to have the first configuration same as the original input. Also it does not provide a way to understand what is the state of permutations evolution.

This alternative solution which is provided(under GNU LGPL version 2 and higher) also encapsulate some additional useful functionalities. A major drawback that I can think of is inability to use iterators. In term of overhead resulted from filling the index array for each permutation, after removing(only from the main function not in the templates) extra functionalities(progress reports and such) and performing a speed test for an input file with 10 lines, there was a little to no difference between this method and using 'std::next_permutation'(57.2 vs 57.9 seconds). It is also good to note that the required processes for either algorithm compared to the required processes for writing into files and streams may be too few and  there for rendering my speed test useless!

My apologies to @Mustafa Kalzi if this was not what he had in mind or the code is not to his liking in general!

Please feel free to make comments, provide suggestions/corrections and ask questions! Good luck!

Comment: Any code is a code to learn from, thank you much, my friend! 
I will be running and checking it since it is here, there is always something new to learn.

Comment: Dear @MustafaKalzi you're welcome.  If you liked my solution please consider voting for it. And If you feel this answered your question, please consider accepting. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sure, I will upvote your second one as it is similar to the one i made also :))

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the code as @cmdLP suggested. In order to utilize the features of the C++ language you should use the `bool next_permutation (BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last);` function template.

If you do not know how it works, you should take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

I had to change the type of `file_contents` to `std::vector<string>` because `next_permutation` would not work with a single string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation

using namespace std;

string data;
std::vector<string> file_contents;

string permute() {
    string result;

    do {
        for(auto a: file_contents)
            result += a + " ";
        result += "\n";
    } while ( std::next_permutation(file_contents.begin(),file_contents.end()) );

    return result;
}

void accessFile() {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error openning input file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (getline(inFile, data))
        {
            file_contents.push_back(data);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    ofstream OutFile;
    OutFile.open("output.txt");
    if(OutFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error openning output file." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // OutFile << file_contents;
        string result = permute();
        OutFile << result;
        OutFile.close();
    }
}//File

int main()
{
cout << "do you want to run the program?" << endl;
string input;
cin >> input;
if (input == "yes")
{
    accessFile();
}
else
{
exit(1);
}

return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: Thank you! this code I managed to understand and run as it is relatively simple yet effective.. :))

Answer (score 1):

As @cmdLP suggested. In C++ we can use features of C++ and especially algorithms. Discarding your original example, here a more modern C++ solution:

```
// We want to use the stream input iterator and beeing able to read a complete line (and not words only)
class CompleteLine {
public:
    // Friend: Overload extraction operator for this class. Read complete line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, CompleteLine& cl) {std::getline(is, cl.completeLine); return is; }
    operator std::string() const { return completeLine; } // Return the previously read line
protected:
    std::string completeLine{};
};

// Permute the lines of a file
void permute(const std::string& inFileName, const std::string& outFileName)
{
    std::ifstream inFileStream{ inFileName }; // Open the input file (will be closed by destructor)
    if (!inFileStream) {     // ! is overloaded
        std::cerr << "Could Not open infile: '" << inFileName << "'\n";
    }
    else {
        // Read all lines into a vector of strings. The string will contain the whole line
        std::vector<std::string> fileAsLines{ std::istream_iterator<CompleteLine>(inFileStream),std::istream_iterator<CompleteLine>() };

        std::ofstream outFileStream{ outFileName }; // Open the input file (will be closed by destructor)
        if (!outFileStream) {  // ! is overloaded
            std::cerr << "Could Not open outfile: '" << outFileName << "'\n";
        }
        else {
            // Sort strings (lines in file) 
            std::sort(fileAsLines.begin(), fileAsLines.end());
            do {
                // Ouput complete vector, so all strings (lines) of the file
                std::copy(fileAsLines.begin(), fileAsLines.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outFileStream, "\n"));
                outFileStream << '\n';  // To make it easier to read the output
            } while (std::next_permutation(fileAsLines.begin(), fileAsLines.end())); // Next permutation of vector
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I will be trying to re-create and run this code, it looks very code to learn from, really.
Thank you very much, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

@MustafaKalzi, Just for sake of comparison and simplicity I edited my code to use std::next_permutation instead. This is also easy to understand and if you are more pron to using standard libraries you can use it.
Permutation counting and progress report have been omitted which you can easily add it yourself later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

/*assuming that the first argument to the program is the name of
 input file and the second argument would be the name of output file*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //checking if the right arguments have been entered
    if ((not argc) or (argc > 3)) {
        std::cerr << "wrong number of arguments " << argc - 1 << "should be 2"
                << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //opening the input file;
    std::ifstream in_file(argv[1]);
    //checking if the file is opened correctly
    if (not in_file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "can't open input file" << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //creating a vector for  lines
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    //filling the string vector by the reading from the input file lines
    for (std::string one_line; std::getline(in_file, one_line);
            lines.push_back(one_line))
        ;
    //creating an integer and filling it with the number of lines
    const std::size_t lines_count(lines.size());
    //producing an error if there is no line  in the file
    if (not lines_count) {
        std::cerr << argv[1] << " has zero lines!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << argv[1] << " has " << lines_count << " lines" << std::endl;
    //sorting the vector in order to use std::next permutation afterwards
    std::sort(lines.begin(), lines.end());
    //creating and opening the output file
    std::ofstream out_file(argv[2]);
    //checking if the file is opened correctly
    if (not out_file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "can't open output file" << argv[2] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //everything is set. now lets start going forward trough the permutations and writing to the output file!
    do {
        for (std::size_t lines_counter(0); lines_counter < lines_count;
                out_file << lines[lines_counter++] << std::endl)
            ;
        out_file << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(lines.begin(), lines.end()));
    std::cout << "!!!finished!!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input file

```
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Output file

```
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

line 0
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 3

line 0
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 4

line 0
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 2

line 0
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3

line 0
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 2

line 0
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 4

line 0
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 3

line 0
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 4

line 0
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 1

line 0
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 3

line 0
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 1

line 0
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 4

line 0
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 2

line 0
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 4

line 0
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 1

line 0
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 2

line 0
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 1

line 0
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 3

line 0
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 2

line 0
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 3

line 0
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 1

line 0
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 2

line 0
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1

line 1
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 4

line 1
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 3

line 1
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 4

line 1
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 2

line 1
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 3

line 1
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 2

line 1
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 4

line 1
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 3

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 4

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 0

line 1
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 3

line 1
line 2
line 4
line 3
line 0

line 1
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 4

line 1
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 2

line 1
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 4

line 1
line 3
line 2
line 4
line 0

line 1
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 2

line 1
line 3
line 4
line 2
line 0

line 1
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 3

line 1
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 2

line 1
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 3

line 1
line 4
line 2
line 3
line 0

line 1
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 2

line 1
line 4
line 3
line 2
line 0

line 2
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 4

line 2
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 3

line 2
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 4

line 2
line 0
line 3
line 4
line 1

line 2
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 3

line 2
line 0
line 4
line 3
line 1

line 2
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 4

line 2
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 3

line 2
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 4

line 2
line 1
line 3
line 4
line 0

line 2
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 3

line 2
line 1
line 4
line 3
line 0

line 2
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 4

line 2
line 3
line 0
line 4
line 1

line 2
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 4

line 2
line 3
line 1
line 4
line 0

line 2
line 3
line 4
line 0
line 1

line 2
line 3
line 4
line 1
line 0

line 2
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 3

line 2
line 4
line 0
line 3
line 1

line 2
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 3

line 2
line 4
line 1
line 3
line 0

line 2
line 4
line 3
line 0
line 1

line 2
line 4
line 3
line 1
line 0

line 3
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 4

line 3
line 0
line 1
line 4
line 2

line 3
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 4

line 3
line 0
line 2
line 4
line 1

line 3
line 0
line 4
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 0
line 4
line 2
line 1

line 3
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 4

line 3
line 1
line 0
line 4
line 2

line 3
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 4

line 3
line 1
line 2
line 4
line 0

line 3
line 1
line 4
line 0
line 2

line 3
line 1
line 4
line 2
line 0

line 3
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 4

line 3
line 2
line 0
line 4
line 1

line 3
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 4

line 3
line 2
line 1
line 4
line 0

line 3
line 2
line 4
line 0
line 1

line 3
line 2
line 4
line 1
line 0

line 3
line 4
line 0
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4
line 0
line 2
line 1

line 3
line 4
line 1
line 0
line 2

line 3
line 4
line 1
line 2
line 0

line 3
line 4
line 2
line 0
line 1

line 3
line 4
line 2
line 1
line 0

line 4
line 0
line 1
line 2
line 3

line 4
line 0
line 1
line 3
line 2

line 4
line 0
line 2
line 1
line 3

line 4
line 0
line 2
line 3
line 1

line 4
line 0
line 3
line 1
line 2

line 4
line 0
line 3
line 2
line 1

line 4
line 1
line 0
line 2
line 3

line 4
line 1
line 0
line 3
line 2

line 4
line 1
line 2
line 0
line 3

line 4
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 0

line 4
line 1
line 3
line 0
line 2

line 4
line 1
line 3
line 2
line 0

line 4
line 2
line 0
line 1
line 3

line 4
line 2
line 0
line 3
line 1

line 4
line 2
line 1
line 0
line 3

line 4
line 2
line 1
line 3
line 0

line 4
line 2
line 3
line 0
line 1

line 4
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 0

line 4
line 3
line 0
line 1
line 2

line 4
line 3
line 0
line 2
line 1

line 4
line 3
line 1
line 0
line 2

line 4
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 0

line 4
line 3
line 2
line 0
line 1

line 4
line 3
line 2
line 1
line 0
```

Console messages and communications:

```
./program input.txt output.txt
input.txt has 5 lines
!!!finished!!!
```